# Lack of Cloud Monitoring on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Does anyone know whether there is ever likely to be support for Google's Cloud Monitoring on Ubuntu 21.04 systems? It is one of the mainstream disk images they offer when setting up a new VM, but bizarrely there is no support for monitoring. This means I can't even see the realtime memory usage of my servers in the Cloud Console, and I can't see the connection error logs either - which is a significant problem for me given recent connection issues my users have been experiencing.

If there's any workaround, or if anyone has ever managed to get an answer out of Google tech about this, I'd be grateful to know of it.

Comment: Why do you think that Monitoring in Ubuntu 21.04 is not supported? FYI: It is supported.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Cloud Monitoring and Logging Agents on the Ubuntu virtual machine .
Then create an uptime check and specify alerting policy
Then create a custom dashboard and chart . From here you can view your logs. I hope this helps. For further information you can find a Google documentation for Logging and monitoring.